# jQuery, Ajax, ASP.NET MVC 5 (Checking and displaying server status)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Forgive me, newbie here. Sorry for the long post.

I'm looking for some help implementing a server status feature in a web application that I'm working on at work.  I've found a few code bits here and there, but nothing that seems to suit my need.

The closest thing I have found is this http://ajaxref.com/ch6/ping.html

However, I'm not able to get it to work in jsfiddle to customize it.

My end goal is to make it work in a template I bought on wrapbootstrap.

[Link to INSPINIA Server Status Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl0P7.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: you can check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) it will be useful to raise your content quality

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wade27/k1j9LuL0/  This is what I have on Jsfiddle

Comment: In JavaScript Console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ajaxref.com/ch6/ping.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` with use http://ajaxref.com/ch6/ping.html. Apparently on the server that you do check up or down must be enabled CORS

Comment: Thanks Willie, I've searched around for 2 days trying to solve this.  I'm now just reaching out to different communities for help. Are you familiar with doing a simple server status check like this?

Comment: @Wade on server that you check to up or down must be enabled CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thank you Mikhail.  I will look into this.

Comment: @Wade Perhaps you can get some help here http://enable-cors.org/index.html